# Downloadable photos of smartphones

Tags: images

I'm working on a project which the main goal is to help on smartphone sales. It displays prices, specs and photos. Prices and specs i got covered, but i'm having trouble with the photos.

The main issue is that the ones i have (another employee downloads them from various sources) do not have the same height and width, and when i try to adjust them using css, most of the time they get blurry or really stretched.

Is there a place where i can find smartphone photos that have the same width and height among them?